# How to mock a module but not all the methods in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have a test that mocks like this:

```
@mock.patch('sources.segment.handler.datetime')
    def test_prepare_data(self, mock_datetime):
        utc_time_now = datetime(2019, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1)
        mock_datetime.utcnow.return_value = utc_time_now
```

and a method in `handler.py` that does this:

```
def prepare():
    ....

     data["received_at"] = datetime.utcnow().strftime(time_format)[:-3]
    data["created_at"] = datetime.strptime(record["receivedAt"], utc_offset_format).strftime(time_format)[:-3]
```

the issue is taht the data has a `created_at` field with a MagicMock object instead of a date string. How do I mock the `utcnow` method but not the `strptime` and `strftime` methods?

Answer (score 1):

You can make a subclass of `datetime.datetime` that overrides `utcnow`:

```
class mock_datetime(datetime):
    @classmethod
    def utc_now(cls):
        return datetime(2019, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1)
```

so that you can patch `datetime` with this subclass instead:

```
@mock.patch('sources.segment.handler.datetime', mock_datetime)
def test_prepare_data(self):
    ...
```

Demo: https://repl.it/repls/DarkmagentaTwinDebugmonitor

Comment: I'm getting an importError when I do it this way:  `No module named 'sources.segment.handler.datetime'; 'sources.segment.handler' is not a package
`

Comment: I see. I've updated my answer with a different approach then.